# Filter just the last return from a point cloud

Tags: qgis, lidar, point-cloud

At 3.32.3, the *Processing Toolbox > Point cloud extraction > Filter* tool does not include the ability to select only the **last return** in its list of filter expressions.

This functionality is available in ArcGIS Desktop 10.8 under the *LAS to Multipoint* tool.  I'm looking for a similar QGIS capability.

How do I extract only the last return, regardless of the number returns in a sequence?

Comment: I grabbed some random sample data to test. If these fields are available in your data try ReturnNumber = NumberOfReturns in the expression.

Comment: Perfect - a very clever approach!  I tried it with my data and it worked just fine. If you'd like to convert your comment to an answer I'd be happy to give you credit.

Comment: Thanks. I added the answer. Glad it worked out for you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turns out you can use ReturnNumber = NumberOfReturns in the filter expression to obtain last returns only.

Answer (score 3):

LAS2LAS in LASTools, which should also be in your Processing Toolbox, includes a filter "by classification or return" which allows you to keep "last_only".

[image]